# Bundler::Git error on app startup (passenger 4, nginx flavor, and jruby 1.7.3 for the app under rvm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, jruby, passenger

There are many similar questions, but they are rather dated. The error is familiar, but updated now for passenger 4.0.0.2 and jruby 1.7.3.

The web application cannot be started, and in the stack trace is

> The git source is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start
>   your application (Bundler::GitError)

I have tried a couple things suggested by other posts, such as `bundle install --development`
I have also tried the suggestions per the rvm passenger instructions to no avail.

Another curious thing, I cannot run passenger-status under the jruby gemset, and get this error, `Gem::LoadError: Could not find passenger (>= 0)` I double-checked and made sure passenger is also installed under this gemset.

My nginx config is pointing to the proper ruby wrappers, so that is also not the source of the error. I still have a hunch its due to the different gemsets, as well as having to use MRI ruby for the passenger installation (per recommendation by the Phusion team), but can't seem to pinpoint the source of the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**edit** 
upon closer inspection of the environment variables, GEM_PATH is being left blank
**edit 2** I installed the passenger gem, and did bundle install --deployment under the global gemset for jruby and now am getting gem load errors

> You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.5. Using bundle
>   exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a variety of things, but it all boiled down to, environment variables were not getting set.

Since RVM is moving away from .rvmrc to .ruby-version, it will help to have a solution that will automatically set project-specific virtual environment variables, and for that, I found [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv)

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more, as I'm having the same problems.

Comment: 1st, check that you don't have any line in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.[whatever]rc file thats modifying PATH incorrectly
2nd: do an echo $GEM_PATH, if its blank you have a problem. Try running rvm autodotfiles, and then run source ~/.[whatever]rc